# Deploy django rest api app to production

Tags: django, rest, api, deployment, iis-7

I have created django rest app with python version 3.4.1 and djnago version 1.11.1  abd I am using pyodbc to connect to sql server database. I want to know:

Is it possible to host it using IIS and if yes then how?
Or
What is the best way to host it?

Comment: As far as I know,uwsgi and apache2 is the most common way.

Comment: I succeeded in hosting it on IIS as we are using windows env. Thanks Ykh